# Is it possible to save to disk all info required to kill a process and then start it back up again?

Tags: windows, system, process

I'm thinking of how VM's work but at the level of a regular windows OS process.

The idea is, if I could snapshot and unload processes, I'd never have to quit another app due to using up RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not practical in any of the common operating systems.

Comment: could you give me a 1 or 2 sentence "why" or is it too many reasons to get into combined with it being a silly question to begin with :)

Comment: The process will reference lots of system objects like window handles, file handles that you can't persist. Plus there's the issue of any locks that the process might hold.